# Rails - Multiple development instances with a single source and database.yml file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment

Can we connect to `multiple development instances` with a **single** source and a single `database.yml` file? I mean, I need to have 4 development instances from same source which connects 4 different MySQL databases. Can I start the servers by using different `PORT ID`s?

example:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: TEST1_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 30

development-2:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: TEST2_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 30

development-3:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: TEST3_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 30

development-4:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: TEST4_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password: password
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 30
```

Then, then how we can start 4 different servers (at localhost) connecting these 4 databases simultaneously? (we normally use `rails server` for single instance in development.)

Thanks :)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is super easy.

Just update your `database.yml` file as given in the question. Suppose our development instances are `development`, `development-2`, `development-3` and `development-4`.

First you just create 3 copies of the environment file `development.rb` (can find inside`config/environments/`) and rename it to `development-2.rb`, `development-3.rb` and `development-4.rb`.

Then, just do run the below steps before starting the servers.

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake db:create (OR just rake db:create as it defaults to development)
RAILS_ENV=development-2 rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=development-3 rake db:create
RAILS_ENV=development-4 rake db:create

RAILS_ENV=development rake db:schema:load (OR just rake db:schema:load as it defaults to development)
RAILS_ENV=development-2 rake db:schema:load
RAILS_ENV=development-3 rake db:schema:load
RAILS_ENV=development-4 rake db:schema:load

RAILS_ENV=development rake db:seed (OR just rake db:seed as it defaults to development)
RAILS_ENV=development-2 rake db:seed
RAILS_ENV=development-3 rake db:seed
RAILS_ENV=development-4 rake db:seed
```

Then, start all instances with different server pid's as given below.

```
rails s -p 3000 -e development --pid tmp/pids/server.pid (OR rails s by default)
rails s -p 3002 -e development-2 --pid tmp/pids/server.2.pid
rails s -p 3003 -e development-3 --pid tmp/pids/server.3.pid
rails s -p 3004 -e development-4 --pid tmp/pids/server.4.pid
```

That will start all instances simultaneously from the same `source` and a single `database.yml` file. Thank you all for all your replies and help :)-

Comment: if you find yourself starting lots of processes together, check out the `foreman` gem

Answer (score 2):

- You are not limited to the default rails environments. You could just have `development-2`, `development-3` environments. Read [this post on the 37signals blog where DHH talks about that](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3535-beyond-the-default-rails-environments)
- database.yml can read environment variables.

  ```
  development:
    adapter: postgresql
    host: localhost
    database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DATABASE'] %>
    username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER'] %>
    password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  ```

  then make sure these are set when you start your server.

Comment: Thanks Levinalex. Can we run development, development-2, development-3, development-4 instances together?

Comment: as long as they're not trying to listen on the same port or use the same resources: yes that should work.

Comment: Thanks :). It would be great if you could just elaborate how we can do that?

Comment: use different ports. `rails server -p 3000`, `rails server -p 3001` for example.

Comment: But, that will return the message 'A server is already running. Check /tmp/pids/server.pid.'

Comment: `rails server -p 3001 --pid tmp/pids/server.2.pid` (look at `rails server --help`)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)- I've got my answer.